# Automatically select Foundation 4 tab on page load

Tags: jquery, tabs, zurb-foundation

I'm using nested tabs in Foundation 4. When a user is redirected by the server to a specific anchor on the dashboard (for example, `#account-email`, after they've submitted the update email form), I want to load that section automatically instead of forcing them to click through to the sub-section again.

The best idea I've come up with is to grab the anchor from `location.href` and iterate through the nested section anchors, clicking on each one as the user would have to do anyway. Although it's clicking on the correct elements, it just stays on the default tab (note I have the `one_up` option set to `false` already).

**Why?**

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).foundation('section');
    var match = /.+(#[\w-]+)$/.exec(location.href);
    if( match[1] ) {
        var anchors = match[1].split('-');
        console.log(anchors);

        var click = '';
        for( var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++ ) {
            // concat each nested section 
            click += ((i>0) ? '-' : '') +anchors[i];
            $('.title a[href="'+click+'"]').click();
            console.log(click+': '+$('.title a[href="'+click+'"]').html());
        }
    }
});

// output:
// ["#account", "email"]
// #account: Account
// #account-email: Email
```

And my (simplified) markup:

```
<div data-section="auto" data-options="deep_linking: true; one_up: false;" class="section-container auto" style="">
  <div class="section" style="">
    ...first top-level section...
  </div>
  <div class="section active">
    <h2 data-section-title="" class="title"><a href="#account">Account</a></h2>
    <div class="content">
      ...second top-level section: should be displayed for /dashboard#account...
      <div data-section="auto" data-options="deep_linking: true; one_up: false;" class="section-container auto">
        <div class="section active">
          <h3 data-section-title="" class="title"><a href="#account-email">Email</a></h3>
          <div data-section-content="" class="content">
            ...email sub-section: should be displayed for /dashboard#account-email...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" style="padding-top: 0px;">
          <h3 data-section-title="" class="title"><a href="#account-password">Password</a></h3>
          <div data-section-content="" class="content">
            ...email sub-section: should be displayed for /dashboard#account-password...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you break up the HAML in generated html ? this would be easy for other users who don't know HAML including me to help you :)

Comment: @Jigar, sure, I've replaced the HAML with HTML.

Comment: i replicated the exact code at my end & its working fine.. I do see the console.log msgs as well as proper nested tab gets open based on id in URL